# Cordova App keep crashing on Android device when build in release

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

Hej Guys

I have developed a cordova crossplatform app which if build in debug works fine but when build in release the app keeps crashing. Following are the versions I am using.

- Cordova-cli: 8.0.0
- Cordova-android: 7.1.1
- Npm: 6.4.1
- Node: 8.12.0

I have an idea about that its com.android.support libraray which is causing the problem as in my build.gradle file there are multiple versions of the support library.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:27.+"
compile "com.android.support:support-v13:27.+"
compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2"
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.+"
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
```

}

From what i have read from different sources the library version should be aligned to use the same version.

I am using cordova-android-support-gradle-release plugin to fix android-support version to 26.+. If I set the android-support version less then 26.+ then i get the following error: [Constructor Builder in class Builder cannot be applied to given types](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/676)

The Plugins which are setting the support library version in my solution are:

- phonegap-plugin-push: plugin-version: 2.2.3, support-library-version v13:27.+
- phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner: plugin-version: 8.0.0, support-library-version v4:27.+
- cordova-plugin-file-opener2: plugin-version: 2.0.19, support-library-version v4:+
- cordova-plugin-camera: plugin-version: 4.0.3, support-library-version v4:24.1.1+

How do I align Support library versions? Should i edit the Plugin.xml of the plugin which is setting the Support library version or should I create a Build-extra-gradle file? 
Is It com.android.support library that is causing the app to crash if yes then why is the app not crashing when build in debug?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: I got the Support versions aligned and its working. I did not test the app functionality fully to see if something is broken. Release was not working because the apk was not signed.